# Ошибка: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: веб-программирование, php

Я начал изучать PHP на днях и немогу понять ошибку. Когда я пишу код

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); // и вообще пытаюсь послать любой заголовок
```

то PHP говорит:

> `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by` // мой скрипт на первой строке

Скажите, кто посылает заголовки (Apatch php или кто)? И как мне полностью контролировать вывод или отключить автоматическую отправку заголовков?

Comment: Вопрос вызван полным отсутствием представления о HTTP

Comment: Ещё вопрос. Извините, что ещё спрашиваю; но почему с кодировкой windows-1251 (это стандартная в denwer) всё работает, а с кодировкой utf-8( я захотел её использовать и в php.ini и в httpconfig или как там - короче вроде везде указал utf-8) опять та же ошибка; помогите (мне так надоели эти заголовки :( ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитайте [это](http://phpfaq.ru/headers)

Comment: Спасибо теперь по PHP буду искать ответы там

Answer (score 2):

Все заголовки отсылаются браузеру перед выводом первой буквы, так что перед этим кодом, который добавляет строку к стандартным заголовкам, не должно быть ни одного оператора, выводящего текст в браузер, echo, дампы и тп.

даже не должно быть пробела перед открывающим <?php - перепроверь

Comment: использую UTF-8 (WithoutBOM) и будет тебе ЩаЗтЬе! )

Comment: А как это WithoutBOM ведь gомоему BOM это Browser Object Model?

Comment: В данном контексте BOM - это [Byte Order Mark][1].

  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark